# What is bluetooth USB

Tags: usb, bluetooth

What does a pair of bluetooth USB do?

I need a solution to connect one device to my laptopt using pair of bluetooth usb, i.e without cables.

How can I acheive that?

Comment: Most modern laptops have Bluetooth built in, so a USB interface is not needed to communicate with other BT devices. Once paired, each device has access to whatever resources have been configured as permitted on the other.

Comment: What is “What does a pair of bluetooth USB do?” even supposed to mean? What *exactly* do you want to achieve? What “one device”? Does it support Bluetooth? How would it interact with your computer?

Comment: I want to connect few usb devices to my laptop without cables.

Answer (score 1):

So, from your question and comments I gatter what you’re looking for is [Wireless USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_USB). It is the only technology that provides a wireless *USB* connection. However, availability remains very low.

A Bluetooth adapter will provide a wireless *Bluetooth* connection. Bluetooth is a low-bandwidth protocol that is not suitable for raw USB data. It’s specified for up to 50 MBit/s (Bluetooth 5) whereas USB 2.0 is already at 480 MBit/s.

Also, there are no generic “make something Bluetooth-capable” adapters, only specific ones for audio. Those are available everywhere though.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately a stable wireless USB technology doesn't really exist in any real products. There are USP over IP projects, such as this: https://www.virtualhere.com/ but you need 2 computers to do it, inconvenient.

Most people buy USB extension cables and try to hide them as neatly as possible. With an extension cable, you can position the USB device better to maximize the wireless range of many proprietary wireless products, like Mice, Keyboards, and game controllers.